# Angular 5 HttpClient 'get' call returns array if 2+ results but not an array on 1 result

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

On my test Angular 5 web client, on this HTTP call to my Java Jax-RS REST server I expect a return of data as array of type - PlayerRecord. (It is a simple class with a few fields).

```
 this.http.get<PlayerRecord[]>(this.url)
        .subscribe(data => this.onDataSuccess(data), 
                    err => this.errorHttp.set(err));
```

I am handling the data in the below function with parameter that expects data to be again an array of type - PlayerRecord:

```
playerRst: PlayerRecord[];

private onDataSuccess (data: PlayerRecord[]) {
    this.playerRst = data;
    console.log(this.playerRst.length);
    console.log(this.playerRst[0]);
    ...
}
```

Now, if the result has 2 or more elements in the array, I do get the expected array of data fine, HOWEVER, if I get only 1 record from the server, 'data' is no more an array and the steps in the onDataSuccess function fail.

Can you please explain why TypeScript can't keep an 1 element array as array or what I am missing, and how to work around this?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please include the response data.

Comment: 99% that its server is sending one object instead of array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely your backend.

If a query such as get player record can returns multiple records then your backend should return a list even if that list contains a single element otherwise you will have problem like this due to response being parsed.

It doesnt make any sense to have a service call that sometime returns a single object and other time a list of object and then angular expecting an array of object to map.

Comment: Good point. I should have looked a at the server end, what it returns. Thanks.